# What's a word for something that requires focus for a long time?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

The opposite of "quick". For a example:

> Washing the dishes is a quick task

But

> Writing an essay is a _ task

I'm looking for an adjective (so no "task that requires focus"), preferably one that isn't opinionated about the task itself, so no "onerous" for example.

Comment: *time-consuming*

Comment: pains-taking?  .

Comment: Possibly "exacting" ?

Comment: How about "a demanding task"?

Comment: You're going to run into problems with this. When you say the opposite of *quick*, what time frame are you looking at? Hours, days, weeks, months, years, or a lifetime are all possibilities. Depending on what you mean, different words could be used. While some could apply to many of those time periods, *lifelong* (for instance) would be something specific.

Comment: Opposite of quick? Try a thesaurus.

Comment: Writing an essay is a **lengthy** task. I know  you are not looking for this word particularly.  So, I suggest you to change the example sentences.

Comment: It seems the OP intended *washing the dishes is a quick/easy/silly task*. Then, writing an essay is a **serious** task.

Comment: I'm unclear on whether the *or* in the title should be **or** or **for**.

Comment: Extended.  In high school, exams include multiple choice, short answer, and "extended response."  The other example that comes to mind is "extended breastfeeding."

Comment: Please include your research!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the word 'Lengthy' can fit your essay sentence.

Comment: Exactly! But I guess, OP is looking for something else.

Answer (score 1):

As in:  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/time-consuming)

- > Writing an essay is a **time-consuming** task.

> taking up much time

Answer (score 1):

Writing an essay is an `engrossing` task

Cambridge Dictionary: adj. very interesting and requiring all your attention

Comment: doesnt that sound a little *gross*?

Comment: @vectory not without a gross misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

> [intensive](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/intensive)
>
> 1. Thorough; to a great degree; with intensity.
>
> *Secondly, I continue to base my concepts on intensive study of a limited suite of collections, rather than superficial study of every packet that comes to hand.*
>
> 2. Demanding; requiring a great amount of work etc.
>
> *This job is difficult because it is so labour-intensive.*
>
> 3. Highly concentrated.
>
> *I took a three-day intensive course in finance.*
>
> 4. (obsolete) Stretched; allowing intension, or increase of degree; that can be intensified.
> 5. Characterized by persistence; intent; assiduous.

The polysemy displayed by the definitions shows some senses that fit very well, others that don't. I'm inclined to think that it would be better with a qualifying noun attribute for clarity

> *Washing the dishes is not a* labor-intensive *task*
>
> *Writing an essay is a* time-intensive *task*.

Yet, the metonym of both senses is not in my humble opinion *intensive*. Writing a stackexchange answer for example should rarely be an intensive task. We up-vote *extensive* answers, but discourage *trivial* drivel.

Between *extent/intent, intention/extension*, the sense that does fit the wanted meaning is not readily recognizable from the stem(s). Yet, a literal translation to Ger *an-strengend* confirms my idea, where *streng* obviously compares to *strength, tension*. Eventually the prefix does occlude the idea. Compare instead *[tedious](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tedious), [strainious](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/strainious)* (in which, I do note so frequently, *s-* may be tried as a prefix ca. *ex-* "out" itself, compare "utmost" for the intensifying sense of "out").

Answer (score 0):

**extended**

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/extended) definition:

> 1 : drawn out in length especially of time | *an extended visit*

Some more examples:

- In high school, exams include multiple choice, short answer, and "extended response."
- Breastfeeding beyond age two-ish is known as "extended breastfeeding."

In your example sentence, *involved* would also fit.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a task that requires a lot of concentration, there is a number of adjectives which might fit your sentence. Most of them, however, imply interest and/or pleasure in doing this work:

- **absorbing**: intensely interesting; engrossing.
- **preoccupying**: dominating or engrossing the mind of (someone) to the exclusion of other thoughts
- **gripping**: firmly holding the attention or interest; exciting.
- **riveting**: completely engrossing; compelling.
- **enthralling**: capturing and holding one's attention; fascinating.

By a long shot, I'd say "**meditative**" is possible in this context (as in, relating to or absorbed in meditation or considered thought.)

By an even longer shot...

- **painstaking**: done with or employing great care and thoroughness.
- **meticulous**: showing great attention to detail; very careful and precise.
- **scrupulous**: careful, thorough, and extremely attentive to details